# How to Post feed & photos in within FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook

My working code : How to Post feed & photos in within FB.api!?

```
var opts = {
    message : data1,
    access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
    link : 'http://jonmosley.co.uk',
    description : 'Descriptionhdofh odfoidf  doifo here',
    url : 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DL_O7D5V4AApO24.jpg'
};
FB.api('/me/photos/feed', 'post', opts, function(response){
if (!response || response.error){
        console.log(response.error);
        alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }else{
        alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi a example of using **Facebook API Graph v2.2** simple access social network :

Showing some information feed :

```
function facebook(id) {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/' + id + '/feed?limit=1&access_token=443213172472393|l2IEt1tuyYta_278fR5NAg8V1jI',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(json) {
      var data = json.data[0],
          poto = '',
          html = '';
      if (data.picture != null && data.picture != undefined) {
          poto += '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + data.object_id + '/picture" class="media">'
      }
        var url = {
            link: 'https://facebook.com/',
            tag: 'https://facebook.com/hashtag/'
        }
      html += '<div class="post facebook">';
      html += ' <div class="content">';
      html += '     <div class="left">';
      html += '         <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>';
      html += '     </div>';
      html += '     <div class="right">';
      html += '         <div class="top">';
      html += '             <a class="user" href="https://facebook.com/' + data.from.id + '" target="_blank">' + data.from.name + '</a>';
      html += '             <a class="date" href="' + data.link + '" target="_blank">' + relative_time(data.created_time) + ' ago</a>';
      html += '         </div>';
      if (data.message != null && data.message != undefined) {
          html += '         <div class="bottom">';
          html += urltag(data.message, url);
          html += '         </div>';
      }
      html += '     </div>';
      html += ' </div>';
      html += poto;
      html += '</div>';
      $('#feed').append(html);
  });
}
```

Posting feed data to the API :

Javascript

```
var FacebookLike = {
  // You probably don't want to use globals, but this is just example code
  fbAppId: '{YOUR API}',
  objectToLike: '{YOUR URL}'
}

// Additional JS functions here
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: FacebookLike.fbAppId, // App ID
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the
    // server to access the session
    xfbml: true, // parse page for xfbml or html5
    // social plugins like login button below
    version: 'v2.3', // Specify an API version
  });
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function login(title, id) {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      alert("Logged in successfully. You can share on your FaceBook page.")
      postLike(title, id)
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      alert("Please authorize the application");
    } else {
      alert("Please login to FaceBook and authorize the application");
    }
  });
}

function postLike(title, id) {
  var stats = false;
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      stats = true;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      var success = confirm("Please click 'Ok' to authorize the application!");
      if (success) {
        login(title, id);
      }
    } else {
      var success = confirm("Please click 'Ok' login to Facebook!");
      if (success) {
        login(title, id);
      }
    }
  });
  if (stats) {
    title = encodeURI(title);
    FB.ui({
          method: 'share_open_graph',
          action_type: '{graph:action}',
          action_properties: JSON.stringify({
              image: '{..thumbnail.png}',
              certificate: "{..object.php?title=" + title + "&id="+id+"}",
            description: "{external description}",
            title: title,
            course: title,
            type: '{YOUR GRAPH OBJECT: OBJECT}'
          })
      },
      function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Success!';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + response.error_message;
          if (response.error_code == 100) {
            alert('Sorry! The application is not allowed to post on the FaceBook. Please contact support.');
          } else {
            alert('Sorry! The application could not post on the FaceBook. Please contact support.')
          };
        }
      });
}
return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

I hope that help, regards.

Comment: FB.ui is not FB.api